Remote login screen automatically disables settings in 24.04 GNOME
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with a GNOME desktop. I have been using RDP to login, and the other day it stopped working. After ensuring all my router settings were correct, I went back to the "Remote Login" settings screen in Ubuntu and found that Remote Login was disabled.
I put in my password to unlock the screen and enabled Remote Login,  however it almost immediately grays out and none of the other fields in the screen are enabled. After about 20 seconds it disables itself and I have no option to re-enable or unlock. If I close Settings and return at any point in this, it shows as disabled.
I have verified that I have openssh installed, but I can't figure out why it won't work and (most frustratingly) why it stopped working after previously working.
Before unlocking:

After unlocking:

After enabled - note that port/username/password are all still grayed out:


I was able to fix this by doing a distribution upgrade to 24.10.  Not the ideal solution, but there are a few things upstream that I wanted anyway...
